# Why can't I just group by date(startTime) here?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a date/time field in my table called startTime.

I would like the output as follows:

```
select
YEAR(startTime),
MONTH(startTime),
DAY(startTime),
dayofmonth(startTime),
startTime,
...
```

This is fine, and I only have to group by startTime.

However, for my output, I am only really interested in the date part of the startTime.

So I changed my output to be

```
select
YEAR(startTime),
MONTH(startTime),
DAY(startTime),
dayofmonth(startTime),
DATE(startTime),
...
```

When I try to run this, SQL makes me group by Year, Month, day, dayofmonth and date(startTime).

This seems to be a quirk of the date() function?

I thought maybe it's due to the time part of the startTime field, but Year, Month, Day and dayofmonth are no more granular than a date so I am confused as why I have to group by those.

Any insights greatly appreciated!

My code currently:

```
YEAR(startTime),
MONTH(startTime),
DAY(startTime),
dayofmonth(startTime),
date(startTime),
count(id)

from
bookings

group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

in your select statement we must have distinct values of selected column (as a group) for every distinct value given value of what we group them by.

For example if you have startime in your select clause, and also in group by clause, we get distinct values of selected attributes - date, month, year, & startTime for every unique value of starttime. But if you remove starttime from select clause, the attributes selected are no longer guaranteed to be unique.

Consider 2 startTime values 2020-03-12T01:01:01.000UTC and 2020-03-12T02:02:02.000UTC its expected to produce two rows if we group by startTime (as two distinct startTimes), but the selected values for year, month and date would be same in both of these rows (as they differ only in time part) which is breaking the group by contract.

Hence we can only have group of attributes in select clause which MUST provide a different value for every combination of attributes in the group by clause.